# Why does git rev-parse --show-toplevel return different casing than actual path

Tags: git

I am using an npm package that uses `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the top level path of my git repo.

My actual path (this is on windows) is

`C:\grde\username\so-on`

but git returns

`C:\GRDE\username\so-on`

Why does it capitalise the first folder like that?

This is breaking this package as it uses the returned value to store a reference. This does not work though as when trying to lookup the reference is is comparing `C:\grde` with `C:\GRDE`

Update:

The result of `dir` in `C:\` does actually show the uppercase version of the name. In explorer however it shows the lowercase name. How annoying. It seems that node and git have different ways of resolving the file path.

Comment: How have you determined that the "actual" path is lowercase?  What's the output of `dir C:\`?

Comment: The Windows file systems are case-insensitive. Windows Explorer shows that uppercase name in lowercase probably because of some code written for Windows 95 when on the disk there were long file names (mixed case) generated by Windows 95 programs and short file names (stored as uppercase) generated by the MS-DOS programs.

Comment: @axiac NTFS is case sensitive. That's the api that hide this case sensitivity (which most file system experts think it's a non sense...)

Comment: @Philippe NTFS preserves the case when it creates files but it is case insensitive when it searches for files.

Comment: @axiac you just confirmed what I said ;)

Comment: @Philippe no, I just said that NTFS does not change the case of the file name. But it is not case-sensitive. Please check the fourth bullet item in this list (it is official Microsoft documentation about disk operations on Windows): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#naming-conventions It clearly says *"Do not assume case sensitivity. ... Note that NTFS supports POSIX semantics for case sensitivity but this is not the default behavior"*.

Comment: @axiac once again, what you tell and show me says clearly that you could store file in ntfs with case sensitivity support. That's the Win32 namespace APIs (especially the read ones) that hides you this case sensitivity.

Comment: @Philippe do you think that somebody cares how the file name is stored inside the file system? As long as one searches for `oscar`, `Oscar` and `OSCAR` and gets the same file, that file system is not case sensitive.

Comment: @axiac Oh, I just would like to correct your first sentence (we are on StackOverflow because we like accuracy, no!?!) "the Windows file systems are case-insensitive" because that's the problem exposed by the question. Git use MSys2 that try to be a "POSIX-compatible environment" and so, should use the "NTFS supports POSIX semantics" that is case sensitive. So NTFS is case sensitive! ( fourth bullet item of the list \o/). And the problem here is that it use 2 programs that use the Win32 semantic (case insensitive) and the POSIX semantic (case sensitive) but NTFS support case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Git resolves a path, it canonicalizes the path.  On Unix systems, that means it resolves all symlinks, and on case-insensitive systems, it canonicalizes the case as well.  This is important so that Git can easily determine whether a file is in the repository, among other things.

In this case, your directory is actually uppercase on the file system, but you're trying to access it using the lowercase version.  You can rename the directory with something like [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase) if you want it to be lowercase.  This is, unfortunately, one of the pitfalls of a case-insensitive file system.